# Algorithm that spans two pages in Latex

Tags: algorithm, latex, pdflatex

i have a long algorithm that i need to put in a report. i am using latex for this report. but due to the length of the algorithm it is more than one page but i cannot get it to fit into the next page. i am new to latex. can someone tell me how to do this? i am new to latex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split it into two. If you're using one of the packages that lets you number lines, tell the second half to start with a line number that's one plus the last line number.

You'll probably be able to get better quality answers if you tell us which package you're using to format your algorithm (or ask for suggestions; I've had good results with "[listings](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf)").

Answer (score 2):

You should manually split the algorithm into two parts. You can just chop it in half, as redtuna suggested, or even better, you can factor out an interesting chunk into a new function and put that on a separate page. This will likely make the algorithm more readable too.